# spree edit general setting unauthorized page by cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, spree

I am creating a spree extention which contains only backend, I rewrite the Ability class for using a different roles system, when I want to access to the General Settings (/admin/general_settings/edit) I got redirected to /unauthorized page. Do I am doing something wrong?

I have this in the ability class:

```
can :manage, Config # to be able to show the configuration link
can :manage, Store, id: user.store_id # to be able to show the general settings link
can :manage, Preference
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is no any model declared for the general settings you need to give access in ability to access edit and update method as below

```
can :manage, Spree::Admin::GeneralSettingsController
```

Also, Add a Spree:: to your model names in you ability file
Your Given lines should be like this

```
can :manage, Spree::Store, id: user.store_id # to be able to show the general settings link
can :manage, Spree::Preference
```

Comment: can :manage, Spree::Admin::GeneralSettingsController did not work but can :manage, :general_settings fixed it. I got the idea by analyzing in the authorize_admin method, I think it is not the cleanest way but I tried many another options and no way.